# Are functions with Try/Option signature a pure function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm learning about functional programming and trying to understand pure functions.

Wikipedia says a function is pure if:

1. No Side effects
2. Maps input to output

Pure functions also satisfy referential transparency, do not access a global variable, and does not mutate input variables.

Are partial functions pure?

A function that has a signature type of

```
def foo(x: Int): Option[Int] = { if(x <= 0) None else Some(x) }
def bar(x: Int): Try[Int] = Try { require(x <= 0); x }
```

are these functions pure functions?

They don't map every input to proper output.

I know that declaring the data types as `Option/Try` lets the caller know that it might fail for certain inputs.

Are the above functions pure?

Comment: They do map every input to a proper output. The idea of effect types like **Option** and **Try** is precisely to encapsulate those things in a transparently referential way.

Comment: `def bar(x: Int): Int = { if(x <= 0){ throw new Exception("less than zero")}; x }`
is impure. but by adding a `Try` type makes it pure? how?

Comment: That is a different question, it depends on what you consider pure and impure to mean. But, usually, only academics care about that. Professional FP developers care about RT and composition, because those properties provide a real benefit in our codebase, and that is the ability to reason about it. By adding `Try` your code is RT to the outside and it is composable, so that is good; some people _(like myself)_ would prefer to use something `Either` and raise the error manually instead of throwing it inside the `apply` of `Try` but that is more about code style.

Answer (score 1):

`Try` and `Option` tell nothing whether side effects were used to create them.

```
def parseLong(str: String) = Try(str.toLong)
```

This is pure computation - it doesn't change global state, its output depends only on input. On the other hand:

```
Try {
  // create entry in database
}
```

would change the state of the outside world. Because `Try` and `Future` catch exceptions they are used in "Scala as better Java" as one ways to denote side effects, but you cannot enforce this or any other convention.

If you put side effects into `Try { ... }` they will be evaluated immediately and the result will be memoized, so you'll break referential transparency.

```
// tupled is from Cats
val t = Try{ println("foo"); 10 }

(t, t).tupled.map { case (a, b) => println(s"$a  $b") }
```

is not the same as

```
(Try{ println("foo"); 10 }, Try{ println("foo"); 10 }).tupled
  .map { case (a, b) => println(s"$a  $b") }
```

So whether or not function returning `Try` or `Option` or `Future` etc is pure, depends whether inside of them you perform side effects. This cannot be deduced from type at all. They might be pure or impure and you can only find out by looking inside. Whether they are partial or total also doesn't tell you anything.

In purely FP Scala you would be using some IO instead of `Try` or `Future` to handle code that might be async and/or failing and surely side effecting because it only compute values when it is asked to and every time you ask it to.

```
val t = IO { println("foo"); 10 }

(t, t).tupled.map { case (a, b) => println(s"$a $b") }
```

is the same as

```
(IO { println("foo"); 10 }, IO { println("foo"); 10 }).tupled
  .map { case (a, b) => println(s"$a $b") }
```

Then you'll use IO for all side effecting things, are you'll be very careful to never use anything else for impure computations (well, sometimes you might convert to/from `Future`s). So in such codebases functions returning Option/Either would almost always be pure. At least the parts that the programmers would directly control (libraries can have other conventions).

Comment: While this is totally correct, not sure if OP is already looking at things like `IO` and just wondering if returning an `Option` is considered to respect referential transparency. Which it does compared to its counterpart the `null`, since both are concerned about the side-effect of a missing value, not the side-effect of mutability or I/O operations.

Comment: `Try` isn't considerer RT because side effects. If it was it wouldn't be breaking monadic laws and could be considered an actual monad (as opposed to "having monading interface"). `Option` takes pure value so the idea of RT doesn't necessarily makes sense - if there is some side effect it has to be performed before `Option` is created. However OP asked about functions with `Option` and `Try` in signature and Scala doesn't provide any RT guarantees about them, especially if you work with "Scala as better Java" codebase.

Comment: Returning `IO` isn't also a guarantee of not doing side-effects. Also, the idea of RT is bigger than traditional definitions of side-effect. I/O  or mutability are not the only kinds of side effects, returning `null` or throwing an exception are side effects; also contained mutability is not a side effect to external callers. As such, the concept of referential transparency applies to all of them. - Also, **Try** does form a valid **Monad**, as well as, **Future**. They do not form a valid **Sync**, those are different things.